# Where is this Twitter App hiding?

Tags: applications, twitter

I changed my twitter password a while ago, and periodically, when my phone has been off or totally offline, I'll get an alert: "Twitter sign in failed" but the Icon looks like a twitter icon, not Seesmic or Tweetdeck, the two apps I use. I'm assuming the problem from the app perspective is that my password isn't working. From my perspective, the problem is that I can't even figure out what app is sending these prompts. Seesmic and Tweetdeck have my new password, and I don't see a "Twitter" app in my applications anywhere.

How do I even begin to figure out where this alert is coming from?

Comment: What phone? OS? Carrier? Some have it pre-installed. Did you check under `Accounts & sync`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the Social Networking Service (SNS) or a similar application, rather than a Twitter-specific app.  I have this service on my Samsung phone and there's a widget that can display social networking posts on the home screen.  You can manage it via `Settings -> Accounts and sync`, as Al said.